# When is an inode's file_operations linked to its character device file_operations?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am reading the LDD3, and I would like to understand how the device driver file operations are called at the time a system call is performed.

From my understanding, when the open system call is performed, the `struct file *filp` gets its `f_op` attribute populated from the inode's `i_fop`.

But when/where does the inode get its `i_fop` attribute populated with the `cdev`'s `ops` attribute?

My intuition is that when we call `cdev_add` in the driver, our device is added to the `cdev_map` with the MAJOR and MINOR numbers, but the inode is not yet linked to the character device. The inode would only be linked either when `mknod` is called to create the device file in the `/dev` directory, or when the device file is opened through the syscall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struct inode`'s `i_fop` member gets set to `&def_chr_fops` (in "fs/char_dev.c") for character special files by the `init_special_inode()` function (in "fs/inode.c"). That is called by the underlying filesystem (e.g. when it is populating its directory structures and inodes when mounted or when a new character special file is created in the filesystem by `mknod()`.

When opening the file, the `struct inode`'s `i_fop` is copied to the `struct file`'s `f_op` member by the `do_dentry_open()` function called from the `vfs_open()` function (in "fs/open.c"). `do_dentry_open()` calls the `open` file operation handler. For character special files, the `open` file operation handler from `def_chr_fops` is the `chrdev_open()` function (in "fs/char_dev.c").

The `chrdev_open()` function looks up the `struct cdev` (if any) associated with the MAJOR/MINOR device number (from the inode's `i_rdev` member), copies the `ops` member from the `struct cdev` to the `struct file`'s `f_op` member to replace the file operations, and calls the replacement `open` handler if there is one.